# How to export properties of shared case classes

Tags: scala.js

I am trying to share a case class between server and client. I am using upickle on both ends. The objects and their data are nicely available on both ends.

shared class

```
case class Foo(var id : Long,var title: Description)
```

However i need to export the fields of the case class on the client side. I could add the `@ExportAll` annotation, but that means pulling in the scalajs libraries on the server project.

Is there perhaps a better way of exposing the members id and title to the javascript.

tx.,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right way to export things to JavaScript is to use the `@JSExportAll` annotation. You cannot, and should not, pull the Scala.js libraries on the server project, though. For this use case, we have a dedicated JVM artifact, `scalajs-stubs`, which you can add to your JVM project like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %% "scalajs-stubs" % scalaJSVersion % "provided"
```

As a "provided" dependency, it will not be present at runtime. But it will allow you to compile the JVM project even though it references `JSExportAll`.

See also [the ScalaDoc of scalajs-stubs](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-stubs/0.6.0/#package).