# How can I export scala seq to js.Array in case classes

Tags: scala, scala.js, case-class

This question is a question related with [How to export properties of shared case classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413266/how-to-export-properties-of-shared-case-classes)

In case I have a case class of the form

```scala
case class Foo(var id : Long,var title: Seq[String])
```

i.e. it contains a sequence of data, is there any setting to be exported as `js.Array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use in general upickle, the way I went around is by using generics in the shared project
i.e.

```
case class Foo[S[_]](var id : Long, var title: S[String])
```

in scala JVM I pickle the case class as an object of the form

```
Foo(id, Seq(title1, title2, ...))
```

which it is an object of type `Foo[Seq]` and in scala JS I pickle the object as 
`Foo[js.Array]` .

Answer (score 0):

In a Scala.js-only project, one would simply do the following:

```
case class Foo(var id: Long, var title: Seq[String]) {
  @JSExport("title")
  protected def jsTitle: js.Array[String] =
    title.toJSArray

  @JSExport("title")
  protected def jsTitle_=(v: js.Array[string]): Unit =
    title = v.toSeq
}
```

however, this will refuse to compile in shared sources, because Scala/JVM does not know about `js.Array`.

I'm afraid there is no boilerplate free solution to your problem. The easiest solution would be to declare `Foo` separately in the JVM and JS parts of your project. You can then still use it from the shared sources.